# What Data Structure works best for this problem?

Tags: data-structures, python

I have 2 sets of atmost 25000 4-tuples. Currently, I am storing them as 2 lists of 4-tuples A and B.

I have to perform the following computation for each of the combinations of A and B.

```
min(B[j][0], B[j][2])<=A[i][0] and max(B[j][0], B[j][2])>=A[i][0] and B[j][1]>=min(A[i][1], A[i][3]) and B[j][1]<=max(A[i][1],A[i][3])
```

To get i and j values, I am using a Generator in Python.

```
def combi(LA, LB):
    for ii in range(LA):
        for jj in range(LB):
            yield (ii,jj)
```

Then I just loop through all the combinations and count how many are true.

```
for i,j in combi(len(A), len(B):
    count = 0
    f = do_above_computation
    if f:
        count +=1
print(count)
```

Someone suggested me to use Fenwick Tree instead of List of Tuples, but all the examples I found were for Cumulative Sum and I haven't figured out how it could work for this problem.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Then, there are data structures for *static problem*s (all values known from the outset) and dynamic variants - sets change with deletions & additions. [Python mechanisms](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) aside: Can you think of a geometric interpretation of the $B_j$ and $A_i$? A count being required doesn't mandate counting from zero in increments of one.

Comment: Please provide a url to the original problem as well as some examples of the suggestions to Fenwick Tree and "all the examples" you have found.